# Calculus: Find area between $f(x)=x^{4}-5x^{2}$ and $g(x)=-4$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

so I have this math problem:

> The graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ intersect at more than two points.
>   Find the total area of the regions that are bounded above and below by
>   the graphs of $f$ and $g$.
>
> $f(x)=x^{4}-5x^{2}$
>
> $g(x)=-4$

I'm not entirely sure as to where to start. I find the intersections points to be $x=-2, -1, 1, 2$

However, I did this on my calculator when I have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to find the intersection points by hand, note that if we set
$$a(x)=x^2 - 5x + 4$$
then
$$f(x)-g(x)=a(x^2).$$
So you just need to factor $a$, which isn't too bad and note that if $x^2$ is a root of $a$, then $x$ is a root of $f(x)-g(x)$ - i.e. an intersection. In general, just notice that there are no odd powers involved in either polynomial, so they are polynomials of $x^2$.

Of course, given that you know the intersection, verifying that they intersect there is rather easy. Note that in $[-2,-1]$, the function $f$ is below $g$, so you integrate $g-f$ and in $[-1,1]$ the function $f$ is above $g$ so you integrate $f-g$ and in $[1,2]$ the function $f$ is again below $g$. It's should be relatively trivial to integrate those polynomials over those integrals.

Comment: The part I got confused on was "above and below"

Comment: I mean that, for instance, for any x in $[-2,-1]$, so $f(x)<g(x)$ meaning $|f(x)-g(x)|=g(x)-f(x)$. Knowing this, the quantity you want to integrate is $\int_{-2}^2 |f(x)-g(x)|$, so you just split the integral into the intervals where $f(x)-g(x)$ is positive ("f is above g") and where it is not

Comment: Ok, so I can just solve for 3 separate integrals (-2 -> -1; -1 -> 1; 1 -> 2), and that's it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Ok, so I got -328/15, -164/15, and -328/15... Do I take the absolute value of each and add them?

Comment: It seems like you made a sign error and integrated g-f when f-g would have been appropriate and vice versa (but that only changes the sign on the answer) - but other than that, yeah, when you sum the values (which should be positive), you get the answer.

Comment: Above on your answer you said for [-2 -1] you integrate g-f...right? or is it f-g?

Comment: When I integrate $f(x)-g(x)$ on the interval $[-2, -1]$ I get $-22/15$, which is also negative.

Comment: I *think* that's right, but if the integral comes out negative, then I must be wrong and it should be done the other way.

Comment: Hmmm, both of the ways come out negative... I may be doing something wrong

Comment: $\int_{-2}^{-1} x^4-5x^2+4=\frac {-22} {15}$ $\int_{-2}^{-1} -4-x^4-5x^2=\frac {-328} {15}$